# Creating weblogic domain for SOA and extending it silently

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic, soa, oracle-fusion-middleware

To start with, I have to say that I am not an oracle developer and I have never used any oracle product. But I have a task in hand to automate Fusion Middleware. I have automated the installation using response files. However, I Am not sure how to create the soa domain and extend it to include soa components.

I am using this document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e12036/toc.htm
(steps 8,9 and 10). MAnually, using the GUI i am able to do it but I need to automate it. I know it can be done via wlst scripts. Does anyone have a sample script as per the documentation?Unfortunately, I dont have much time to understand wlst scripting. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exact parts do you need scripted? Creating the domain? Adding servers to the domain? Setting up jdbc? You can do all of that with WLST. There are lots of examples out there like: http://crispcode.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/wls-script-to-create-weblogic-domain/

Comment: Thanks .. All of it actually. Just need to do as mentioned in the document  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e12036/create_domain.htm#BABIFBHJ